# IIS enable 32-bit application causes site to fail

Tags: iis, x86

I have a .net website that runs on IIS

I have a new requirement that needs to reference a 32-bit .dll

If I go to my application pool on IIS and check the 'Enable 32-Bit Applications' it causes the following error in my site:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ChilkatDotNet45' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

I thought that by enabling 32 bit applications I was only facilitating them if they exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All assemblies need to have the same (matching) bitness. Thus, if your main application is 64-bit, you can only use 32-bit DLLs. If you need to use a 32-bit DLL, you will need everything to target 32-bit. A 64-bit DLL cannot be loaded into a 32-bit process, nor vice versa.

Comment: I downloaded the 32 bit version of ChilkatDotNet45 and it works now. If you want to put your comment in an answer Ill accept it